# Is it possible to generate an Excel with Slicers with Python? And with the XlsxWriter library?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, slicers

I would like to be able to incorporate Slicers (access buttons to column filtering options) in the Excel sheet from python code.

Would there be any way?

I would like to start from this code:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('tables.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

data = [
    ['Apples', 10000, 5000, 8000, 6000],
    ['Pears', 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
    ['Bananas', 6000, 6000, 6500, 6000],
    ['Oranges', 500, 300, 200, 700],

]

worksheet.add_table('B3:F7', {'data': data,
                               'columns': [{'header': 'Product'},
                                           {'header': 'Quarter 1'},
                                           {'header': 'Quarter 2'},
                                           {'header': 'Quarter 3'},
                                           {'header': 'Quarter 4'},
                                           ]})

workbook.close()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That feature isn't supported by XlsxWriter and, due to the relative complexity, it probably won't be in the future.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer me. 
I really appreciate your work.